# Finding X-Path/Loading data in Google Sheets

Tags: html, xpath, google-apps-script, web-scraping

I am very new to this & I am trying to use the Google Add-On "ImportFromWeb" to scrape NBA Play by Play data into a Google Sheet.

I have inspected the page, but does each item in the HTML code have a separate XPath? I am supposed to be able to paste the link & the Xpath in, but I cannot get the data to load.

I don't think I am selecting the right line? Would anyone be able to tell me which line of code corresponds with the actual play by play data on this site?

https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/202003110ATL.html

Or any way in general to get this play by play info loaded into a document by using the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula which makes use of [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) -

`=IMPORTHTML("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/202003110ATL.html","table",1)`

Should get you the display in a sheet that looks like this -

[image: playbyplay]

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for!! Thank you SO much